# Sharding In MongoDB without Replication

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I want to deploy sharding in mongodb. And I have only 3 Ubuntu servers. Is it possible with 3 servers (1 for config and 2 for sharding)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me cite what you can find [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-requirements/).

> Sharding is the only solution for some classes of deployments. Use
>   sharded clusters if:
>
> - your data set approaches or exceeds the storage capacity of a single    MongoDB instance.
> - the size of your system’s active working set will soon exceed the    capacity of your system’s maximum RAM.
> - a single MongoDB instance cannot meet the demands of your write    operations, and all other approaches have not reduced contention.
>
> If these attributes are not present in your system, sharding will only
>   add complexity to your system without adding much benefit.

---

If you want to use sharding for learning or testing purposes then you could go with the [minimal sharded clusters cluster](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharded-cluster-architectures-test/).

You'll need

- one config server
- one router (mongos instance)
- 1 or more shards

So in your case it is not easy to do, since you want to have 2 shards. So you would need 4 servers.

However, maybe you can try to put the config and the router on the same machine.

Comment: Thanq Elyasin,. I put configsvr and router on the same machine.